# WPF есть ли будущее?

Tags: wpf

Навеяно статьей на хабре: [Семь лет WPF: что изменилось?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/165273/). Болталония конечно, но все-таки хотелось бы узнать мнение сообщества по этому поводу. Судя по статье развития никакого (или почти никакого). Может стоит переползать потихоньку на другую технологию? Чего делать не особо хочется - нравится мне WPF

Comment: Майкрософт давно дала ответ - [Going Native](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative)! :)

Comment: Переход с wpf но нечто более молодое (WP, WinRT) не очень болезненый. Правда миниплюшек в виде мультибайдинга и тригеров не хватает. Сам слез, тк перспективы нет.

Comment: @KoVadim, а если вкратце, то что именно у них (M$) все таки не заладилось с WPF?

Comment: А кто его знает. МС выпускает велосипеды десятками (благо ресурсы пока ещё позволяют). Если велосипед взлетел - ура, придумали чудо. Не взлетел - зарываем.

Answer (score 2):

Я не могу абсолютно точно утверждать что-либо на эту тему, так как WPF практически не занимался, и интересовался им исключительно из соображений любопытства - когда я о нем впервые услышал, он мне показался заслуживающим внимания, а потому мои следующие мысли могут оказаться правильными, а могут и не оказаться.

В общем-то не секрет, что для Microsoft характерно время от времени закапывать свои же перспективные технологии - тут уже упоминался XNA. Из недавнего - Silverlight. Можно также вспомнить MFC. (Впрочем, время от времени их бросает и в другие крайности - если не ошибаюсь, в WinAPI до сих пор/до недавнего времени можно было найти оставшиеся там со времен палеолита бивни мамонтов и украшения из черепов убитых врагов). Помимо тех доводов, что приводились в статье с Хабра могу также сказать, что довольно тревожным для WPF симптомом является то, что MS в последнее время продвигает создание приложений для Win8 на HTML+JS, что возможно видится им как замена для WPF.  С одной стороны (могу ошибаться) WPF обладает рядом вкусных плюшек, которые являются преимуществом этой технологии, но с другой HTML+JS кроссплатформенны (хотя нельзя сказать, что Microsoft  очень уж часто заботил этот вопрос), очень популярны в последнее время (что может позволить привлечь большее число программистов) и просты в освоении. 
Не стану утверждать, что WPF скоро прикроют, серьезных оснований утверждать это нет, но все же вкладывать все свои силы только в него я бы не стал

Answer (score 1):

Тут скорее вопрос предпочтений. Нравится - работай с WPF, не нравится - нет. Мне лично WPF как технология больше нравится, чем WinForms. Тем более развитие все равно слабое но есть, и на WPF МС еще не забила.

Comment: Дак в том то и дело, что "еще не забила". Что-то подобное случилось с XNA - хорошая, на мой взгляд, технология, но тем не менее - прекратили развитие и вообще исправление багов с 2014 прекратят, если я не ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Morogot - от куда данные про то, что еще не забила? Во я вижу, что на рынке новых wpf приложений - только бизнесс сектор. И то он уменьшается.

Comment: Откуда данные? Да вот хотя бы - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb613588.aspx - что-то добавили в новую версию, значит, развивают. Да и не думаю, что все ринутся в создание граф. интерфейсов под Modern (Metro), а для десктопных версий (в режиме раб. стола и предыдущие версии винды) есть только две альтернативы - WinForms и WPF, где WPF выглядит предпочтительнее

Answer (score 1):

Я работал много с WPF. Да, развивается она сейчас чисто на силах не от Microsoft. Но зная мощь и накрученность самого WPF, по-моему, ему и не надо более сложных вещей, чем она имеет (хотя некоторые моменты можно было бы поправить). Дополнительных вещей в виде Frameworks сделано некоторое количество, но opensource слабоват. Лично я предпочитаю делать на базе своих компонентов и классов. WPF работает нормально, и в общем-то используется для создания всех современных интерфейсов окон Windows начиная с 7. От себя скажу, она занимает свою нишу, но что действительно ей не хватает - это производительности графики и применяемых эффектов. Silverlight - прекрасная альтернатива WPF, использующая схожий синтаксис.

Microsoft предоставила WPF для создания интерфейсов пользователя в своей системе, с чем он, по-моему, прекрасно справляется. Но люди больше хотят видеть свои приложения не только на Windows. В любом случае от ручной работы избавиться редактором или бесконечными улучшениями в поддержке не возможно да и не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Тут все зависит от Microsoft. Будет поддерживать - будет будущее. Не будет поддерживать - WPF постигнет судьба WinForms.